# Boxcutter - Mesh error when rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh, add-on, error

I've made some simple cuts using boxcutter, but when I export as an OBJ and open up the mesh in octane, the mesh has some bizarre errors.

There are some triangular pieces of geometry jutting out where I beveled the cutter, and there is some remanence of another cutter, even though I applied all modifiers and made sure the changes were final and no longer live.

[image: Octane Viewport]

Any idea how to fix this, or do I just need to redo all the cuts and re-export?

Comment: I'm not certain this is your issue, but have you (1) merged any duplicate verts, (2) applied scale before finalizing .obj export, and (3) confirmed the face orientation for all faces?

Comment: Thanks @zippy I checked all of it and found the issue.  There was a cutter that somehow got hidden way down in the outliner and was showing up in Octane even thought all modifiers had been applied.  The hidden one needed to be deleted.  Thanks for the reply!